# Add animation on video

Tags: c#, animation, video, winrt-xaml

I want to implement functionality to add animation on existing video in some moment and if it is possible with coordinates (X,Y). Can someone tell me is it possible and how? Is there any library that implement overlaying animations on existing video?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Looks like first question with 0 effort. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: My english isn't so good and I can't explain it in the best way. I want to know is there any way to add animation on video like overlay image on video, but just for some seconds not all the time. I am making an application that generate an animated video from sequence of images, but i want some images to be animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into a `<cavas></canvas>`. And set canvas.left/top to move it.
Or you can do it by changing Margin property.

Comment: Can I save it to new video with this canvas?

Comment: Not in a straightforward way since MediaFoundation is the only built-in tool for encoding videos and there is also no built-in way to save the visual tree of your UI to an image (which is possible in WPF or Silverlight) to say nothing about saving it to a video.